# SQL AUTO_INCREMENT and INSERT MANY VALUES TO ONE ROW

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I'm currently working to get the data from table to another one. However, the old table has 3 rows and my new table has two but one is ID PK. So I want to take the data from this 3 rows and insert them into the `PN` table. The problem here is the `PN_ID`. I'm new to this and any help will be useful. Below is my current code and what I have tried.

This is the table that I want to get the data from:

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES (
NAME_ID varchar(9),
NAME varchar(35),
PN1 varchar(255),
PN2 varchar(255),
PN3 varchar(30)
);
```

And this is the new table where the data will be insert too:

```
CREATE TABLE PN( 
PN_ID INT,
PN VARCHAR (30)
);
```

```
Insert into PN(PROFFESION_ID, PN)
Select  PN1 ||', '||PN2 ||', '||PN3 from NAMES;`
```

The problem here is the `PN_ID`, I would liked to be AUTO_INCREMENT but I did tried different method but non of them work for example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;
```

Comment: You forgot the comma after `seq_person.nextval` in `... Select seq_person.nextval ||  ...` and you also need to remove the concatenation operator after `seq_person.nextval`. Try `... SELECT seq_person.nextval, ', ' || ...`.

Comment: `Insert into PROFFESION(PROFFESION_ID, PROFFESION)
Select seq_person.nextval , PROFESSION1 from NAMES;` should work.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code did work:

```
insert into PROFFESION(PROFFESION_ID, PROFFESION)
select seq_person.nextval, ( PROFESSION1 ||', '||PROFESSION2 ||', '||PROFESSION3) 
from NAMES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks me like the design of the PROFESSION table is not correct. It should have a foreign key to the NAMES table; then, add as many separate PROFESSION rows as are needed to store all the non-NULL `PROFESSIONn` fields in your current NAMES table. THEN, drop the `NAMES.PROFESSIONn` columns. In other words:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFESSION
 (PROFESSION_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME_ID       VARCHAR(9)
    CONSTRAINT PROFESSION_FK1
      REFERENCES NAMES(NAME_ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PROFESSION VARCHAR(30));

CREATE SEQUENCE PROFESSION_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1
  NOMAXVALUE
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NOCACHE;

INSERT INTO PROFESSION(PROFESSION_ID, NAME_ID, PROFESSION)
  SELECT PROFESSION_SEQ.NEXT_VAL, NAME_ID, PROFESSION1 FROM NAMES UNION ALL
  SELECT PROFESSION_SEQ.NEXT_VAL, NAME_ID, PROFESSION2 FROM NAMES UNION ALL
  SELECT PROFESSION_SEQ.NEXT_VAL, NAME_ID, PROFESSION3 FROM NAMES;

ALTER TABLE NAMES
  DROP COLUMN PROFFESION1;

ALTER TABLE NAMES
  DROP COLUMN PROFFESION2;

ALTER TABLE NAMES
  DROP COLUMN PROFFESION3;
```

I also fixed up the spelling of "profession" so it's consistent everywhere.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f08098681472397a6163263d215b210b)